# Apply Auth Middleware to All Laravel Routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

What is the correct way to authenticate all routes except login and register when I apply auth middleware in all controllers? Is there a way to apply auth middleware in one place and exclude login, register routes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can apply middlewares in the routes.php file, what you need to do is to put all your routes on a group, and add the middleware 'auth' ( except the Auth::routes() which are already configured), for example :

```php
Route::middleware(['first', 'second'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        // Uses first & second Middleware
    });

    Route::get('user/profile', function () {
        // Uses first & second Middleware
    });
});
```

more information can be found in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-group-middleware

Answer (score 8):

You can add middleware to your whole `web.php` route file by adding the middleware to your routes mapping in `RouteServiceProvider`.

Go to `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` and in `mapWebRoutes()`, change `middleware('web')` to `middleware(['web', 'auth'])`:

```php
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware(['web', 'auth'])
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}
```

---

##### This is (not?) totally unrelated but here's an *example* of a clean way to handle a lot of route files instead of throwing all your routes into a single `web.php` file:

Create a new method `mapAdminRoutes()`:

```php
protected function mapAdminRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware(['web', 'auth:admin'])
        ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Admin')
        ->name('admin.')
        ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
}
```

Map it:

```php
public function map()
{
    $this->mapWebRoutes();
    $this->mapAdminRoutes(); // <-- add this
    ...
}
```

Create an `admin.php` file in your `routes` folder, then create your routes for Admin:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

// This route's name will be 'admin.dashboard'
Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');

// This route's name will be 'admin.example'
Route::get('example', 'ExampleController@example')->name('example');

...
```

Now you can configure everything in 1 place, like `prefix`, `name`, `middleware` and `namespace`.

Check `php artisan route:list` to see the results :)

Comment: Genuine question - why do we need to add mapAuthRoutes()?  Please illuminate.

Comment: @quinny You don't have to create a new function `mapAuthRoutes`, you can add the Route group to the `mapWebRoutes` function if you like? As long as it is mapped, how you want to do it is up to you. If not mapped, it wont appear on `artisan route:list` and wont work. This method of adding it is just much more cleaner, for me? :)

Answer (score 7):

You can group all your authenticated routes like following, laravel provides a default middleware for auth and guest users

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () { 
    Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::post('save-user', 'UserController@saveUser');
    Route::put('edit-user', 'UserController@editUser');
});
```

The above route names are just made up, please follow a proper naming convention for your routes and controllers. Also read about middlewares over [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware) and about routing over [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing)